# Populate a list of dictionary through a loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I want to generate a list of dictionaries through the loop. I came across that we can use `with_sequence` to generate the integer sequences in ansible. I am getting the following error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

- { "dir": "{{ mat_cleaner_input_file_path_flow }}/{{ item }}" }
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{ http_range }}
      ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"
```

### My config.j2:

```
{{ cleaner_config | to_nice_yaml(indent=2) }}
```

### My task.yml:

```
---
- name: Test dictionaries playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    mat_cleaner_input_file_path_flow: "/var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow"
    mat_cleaner_input_file_path_http: "/var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-http"
    mat_cleaner_input_retention_period: 21600
    http_range: 5
    cleaner_config:
      - { "dir": "{{ mat_cleaner_input_file_path_flow }}/{{ item }}" }
      with_sequence: start=0 end={{ http_range }}

  tasks:
    - name: Set Cleaner Config
      template:
        src: /home/osboxes/CleanerConfig/cleaner.config.j2
        dest: /home/osboxes/CleanerConfig/output
      delegate_to: localhost
      with_items: cleaner_config
```

#### I want the final output file to be:

```
dir: /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/0
dir: /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/1
dir: /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/2
```

Comment: Do you also want it indented?

Comment: @VladimirBotka Yes, basically this jinja template is for another yaml file that will be used by a different application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the output file you want is text. It's not a list. You can create it by [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#), e.g.

```yaml
    mat_cleaner_input_file_path_flow: "/var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow"
    http_range: 3
    cleaner_config: |
      {% for i in range(http_range) %}
      {{ mat_cleaner_input_file_path_flow }}/{{ i }}
      {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  cleaner_config: |-
    /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/0
    /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/1
    /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/2
```

Then, because it's not a list, you don't have to use *to_nice_yaml* in the template. Use [*indent*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.indent) instead if you want to indent the lines, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat cleaner.config.j2
  {{ cleaner_config|indent(2) }}
```

```yaml
    - template:
        src: cleaner.config.j2
        dest: output
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat output 
  /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/0
  /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/1
  /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/2
```

---

Under normal circumstances, you would simplify the code, omit the *cleaner_config* variable, and put the Jinja iteration into the template, e.g.

```yaml
    mat_cleaner_input_file_path_flow: "/var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow"
    http_range: 3
```

```yaml
shell> cat cleaner.config.j2
{% for i in range(http_range) %}
  {{ mat_cleaner_input_file_path_flow }}/{{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

If you want to use a list

```yaml
    mat_cleaner_input_file_path_flow: "/var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow"
    http_range: 3
    cleaner_config_text: |
      {% for i in range(http_range) %}
      - {{ mat_cleaner_input_file_path_flow }}/{{ i }}
      {% endfor %}
    cleaner_config: "{{ cleaner_config_text|from_yaml }}
```

gives

```yaml
  cleaner_config:
  - /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/0
  - /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/1
  - /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/2
```

Now you need *to_nice_yaml* to format the list, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat cleaner.config.j2
  {{ cleaner_config|to_nice_yaml|indent(2) }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat output 
  - /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/0
  - /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/1
  - /var/opt/miq/sftp/edr-flow/2
```